# SQL or TQL based query for GridDb for conditional join

Tags: griddb

I am looking for a way to join or get references from two separate tables based on certain conditions and am not sure if that is achievable or not.

Let me explain that in detail.

I have three tables, which are as follows.

- Brandnames
- RestrictedBrands
- Products

Now I am looking for a way to get the product data only for the brands that are listed in the “RestrictedBrands” table, but I want to add a condition that will consider the **“Brandnames”** table instead of **“RestrictedBrands”** table if the **“RestrictedBrands”** table is empty.

Please consider the following table structure as an example.

**BrandNames table:**

| Brandid | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Hp |
| 2 | IMB |
| 3 | Samsung |

**Brandnames table:**

| Brandid | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | Cisco |
| 4 | Dell |
| 7 | Adobe |

**Products table:**

| productid | brandid | productname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hp | monitor |
| 2 | Dell | LCD |